# Filling an array with random numbers 80-100 and printing two different ways using methods with arrays as parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to have two arrays hold twenty random values from 80-100 but it looks like it's only printing System.Int32[]. It should be attaching values in the FillArray method but I don't think it's working. I might have been staring at this for too long but where am I going wrong?

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] student1 = new int[20];
        int[] student2 = new int[20];
        FillArray(student1);
        FillArray(student2);

        Console.WriteLine("---------- Unsorted ----------");
        DisplayOutput(student1, student2);

        Sort2Arrays(student1, student2);

        Console.WriteLine("---------- Sorted ----------");
        DisplayOutput(student1, student2);

        Console.WriteLine("done");

    } //end main
    public static void FillArray(int[] xArray) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < xArray.Length; i++) {
            xArray[i] = rnd.Next(80, 101);
        } //end for
    }

    public static void Sort2Arrays(int[] xArray, int[] yArray) {
        Array.Sort(xArray);
        Array.Sort(yArray);
    }

    public static void DisplayOutput(int[] xArray, int[] yArray) {
        foreach(int val in xArray) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", xArray, yArray);
        } //end foreach
    } //end display
} //end class
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}",xArray,yArray);` here `xArray` and `yArray` are arrays. You probably want `val` instead, although you are not looping the `yArray` at all, so don't know where you want that value to come from. Do you maybe want a `for` loop and access the two arrays via index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your for loop, now you print your arrays itself and you should print elements of arrays:

```
public static void DisplayOutput(int[] xArray, int[] yArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < xArray.Length; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", xArray[i], yArray[i]);
    }
}
```

I used there `for` loop because you should print elements of both arrays.

P.S This `for` loop is only correct if these arrays have the same number of elements.

**Update**

Or if you want to use `foreach` loop you can write like that:

```
public static void DisplayOutput(int[] xArray, int[] yArray) {
    var arrays = xArray.Zip(yArray, (i, j) = >new {
        x = i,
        y = j
    });
    foreach(var v in arrays) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", v.x, v.y);
    }
}
```

using [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__)

Comment: yess it was the last for loop that messed me up and i didn't even see it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DisplayOutput method was wrong so I've replaced it with

```
public static void DisplayOutput(int[] xArray, int[] yArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", xArray.GetValue(i), yArray.GetValue(i));
    } 
}
```

and it works as it should